# Vector of structs not storing elements after 1st element of vector when reading in from external file

Tags: c++, file, vector, struct

Was having a bit of trouble on one of my labs from my intro to CS course. The purpose of the lab is to put structs of elements into a vector and to read them out using vector notation and the struct datatype. Right now, it works fine except that after it gets through the first element of the vector, it no longer seems to read in into the for loop I have, as when it is printed, it displays the strings in the struct as spaces and the unsigned numbers in the structs as 0s.

External file name: "students.txt"

External file:

```
5
jj432 Jennifer Jones 9 7 10 8 10 4 6 9 0 91 82 93
fh167 Frank Harvey 7 8 8 9 10 6 7 5 0 10 82 81 93 92
ss632 Susan Smith 8 7 10 10 5 0 9 9 8 8 94 88 72 65
ma312 Marie Avalon 4 5 9 6 8 9 7 7 8 6 62 73 79 84
ww785 William Watson 8 9 7 7 8 8 9 10 9 9 94 93 93 100
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void output_header();

const size_t QUIZ_AMOUNT = 10;
const size_t TEST_AMOUNT = 3;

int main()
{
    output_header();

    struct StudentInfo
    {
        string id;
        string first_name;
        string last_name;
        vector <unsigned> quizes;
        vector <unsigned> tests;
    };


    ifstream input_file;
    input_file.open("students.txt");

    unsigned file_header_counting;
    input_file >> file_header_counting;

    vector <StudentInfo> vec_students;

    for (size_t repeat = 0; repeat < file_header_counting; repeat++)
    {
        StudentInfo students;
        input_file >> students.id;
        input_file >> students.first_name;
        input_file >> students.last_name;
      
        for (size_t quiz_loc = 0; quiz_loc < QUIZ_AMOUNT; quiz_loc++)
        {
            unsigned students_quizes;
            input_file >> students_quizes;
            students.quizes.push_back(students_quizes);
        }
        for (size_t test_loc = 0; test_loc < TEST_AMOUNT; test_loc++)
        {
            unsigned students_tests;
            input_file >> students_tests;
            students.tests.push_back(students_tests);

        }

        vec_students.push_back(students);
    }

    for (size_t print = 0; print < vec_students.size(); print++)
        {
            cout << vec_students[print].id << ' '
                 << vec_students[print].first_name << ' '
                 << vec_students[print].last_name << ' ';
                 for (size_t i = 0; i < QUIZ_AMOUNT; i++)
                 {
                     cout << vec_students[print].quizes[i]
                          << ' ';
                 }
                 for (size_t j = 0; j < TEST_AMOUNT-1; j++)
                 {
                     cout << vec_students[print].tests[j]
                          << ' ';
                 }
                 cout << endl;
        }
}




void output_header()
{
    const unsigned ID_FORMAT = 5;
    const unsigned NAME_FORMAT = 12;
    const unsigned QUIZ_EXAM_FORMAT = 18;
    const unsigned PERCENT_FORMAT = 19;
    const unsigned GRADE_FORMAT = 8;

    cout << "********************************************************"
         << "************************" << endl
         << " Student Grade Report" << endl << left << setw(ID_FORMAT)
         << "Id" << setw(NAME_FORMAT) << fixed << "Last Name"
         << setw(QUIZ_EXAM_FORMAT) << "Quiz Percentage"
         << setw(QUIZ_EXAM_FORMAT) << "Exam Percentage"
         << setw(PERCENT_FORMAT) << "Weighted Percent"
         << setw(GRADE_FORMAT) << "Grade" << endl << endl;
}
```

Example of output:

```
********************************************************************************
Student Grade Report
Id   Last Name   Quiz Percentage   Exam Percentage   Weighted Percent   Grade

jj432 Jennifer Jones 9 7 10 8 10 4 6 9 0 91 82 93
   91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 0 0
   91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 0 0
   91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 0 0
   91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 91 0 0
```

I tried messing around with the input system, checking to make sure my external file was correct and didn't have unnecessary whitespace etc, but I haven't had much luck yet. Any/all advice appreaciated.

Comment: part of the problem is that each line of the input has different number of inputs, you need to account for this.

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialise your vector.

```
vector <StudentInfo> vec_students = vector<StudentInfo>();
```